# Php's time() VS MySQL's UNIT_TIMESTAMP() in WHERE clause - which is faster?

Tags: php, mysql, performance, indexing, unix-timestamp

Please fix me if I'm wrong:
So here is the situation. Let's imagine heavy queries MySQL for the website, with lot of request. And MySQL tables can LOCK during the write, so other users will have to wait.
Also as I know, MySQL functions in WHERE clause are rendered on EVERY ROW (?), so it slows don't the query.
While Php's time() is like a static number, for every page load, which does not updates and does not need to be recalculated on every time() call (I believe it is defined in Php kernel's root C/C++ classes as a static variable (?).
Also I know that if I would use:

```
WHERE table_field < '".(time()-86400)."'
```

it would do the subtraction calculation on Php page load, before the MySQL query and would calculate result only once,
but if I would use:

```
WHERE table_field < ".time()."-86400
```

Then it would do calculation on every row. Or am I wrong and MySQL does the caching on same calculation values?

**SCENARIO:** I have **5M rows** length MySQL InnoDB table named **bookings**, with **INDEXes** added to **booking_id**, **booking_status**, **paid**, **booking_timestamp** fields.

**QUESTION:** Am I correct saying, that B is much faster than A:

A - slow, MySQL timestamp():

```
-- Delete Expired bookings
DELETE FROM bookings WHERE booking_paid='0' AND booking_timestamp < (UNIX_TIMESTAMP()-86400)
```

B - fast, PHP's time():

```
-- Delete Expired bookings
DELETE FROM bookings WHERE booking_paid='0' AND booking_timestamp < '".(time() - 86400)."'
```

**QUESTION #2:** What about this situation of fields subtraction:

```
-- Delete Expired bookings
DELETE FROM bookings b
JOIN payment_methods pm ON b.payment_type=pm.method_code
WHERE b.booking_paid='0' AND b.booking_timestamp < (UNIX_TIMESTAMP()-pm.unpaid_booking_expiration_time)
```

VS:

```
-- Delete Expired bookings
DELETE FROM bookings b
JOIN payment_methods pm ON b.payment_type=pm.method_code
WHERE b.booking_paid='0' AND b.booking_timestamp < (".time()."-pm.unpaid_booking_expiration_time)
```

Please answer as deep as you can for this EXACT situation.

Comment: Its best to use mysql datetime operations I think. What happens when the app server's clock gets way out of sync with the database server and you're mixing datetime operations between them?

Comment: also, `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` in the where clause will not run on every row but once before the query begins....the subtraction of a value from a field however will run on every row, even if half of that expression is a literal

Comment: If you use `INNO_DB` it locks the **ROW** and not the whole table as MY_ISAM does,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The cost of function calls and expression evaluation (such as subtract) in SQL is insignificant compared to the cost of finding the row(s) to work on.
- If your web page is hitting thousands of rows, you need to redesign the schema and/or the data flow.
- Use InnoDB (for its row locking) instead of MyISAM (with table locking).
- Functions are evaluated only once:

as seen here

```
mysql> SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), SLEEP(2), UNIX_TIMESTAMP();
+------------------+----------+------------------+
| UNIX_TIMESTAMP() | SLEEP(2) | UNIX_TIMESTAMP() |
+------------------+----------+------------------+
|       1439708367 |        0 |       1439708367 |
+------------------+----------+------------------+

mysql> SELECT NOW(6), SLEEP(2), NOW(6);
+----------------------------+----------+----------------------------+
| NOW(6)                     | SLEEP(2) | NOW(6)                     |
+----------------------------+----------+----------------------------+
| 2015-08-16 00:05:38.941711 |        0 | 2015-08-16 00:05:38.941711 |
+----------------------------+----------+----------------------------+
```